# Probability of sending the message

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I don't know how to compute it clearly, can anyone explain to me ?? Thanks !

When a conventional paging system transmits a message, the probability that the message will be received by the pager it is sent to is ***p***.  To be confident that a message is received at least once, a system transmits the message ***n*** times.**(a)**  Assuming all transmissions are independent, what is the PMF of K, the number of times the pager receives the same message?
**(b)**  Assume ***p***=0.8.  What is the minimum value ofnthat produces a probability of 0.95 ofreceiving the message at least once?

Comment: This is not clear.   We aren't told the nature of the inaccurate messages so we have no way of knowing how often the pager receives the same inaccurate one.  You can do it if you assume they meant to ask about the number of times the pager got the right message.

Comment: @lulu: I don't understand your comment: the question is about whether or not messages are received, not about the accuracy of reception. I would agree that the title of the question is highly misleading.

Comment: @RobArthan  Perhaps i am misunderstanding the question.  I don't understand what "the same message" means.  Suppose I am sending $1$ with a very bad transmitter so I get $0$ ten times.  Is the answer then $10$?  If it were changed to "the number of times the pager receives the correct message" then I understand it.

Comment: @lulu: I see your point. I was reading the question as referring to just one message (which makes sense if you ignore that word "same"). Perhaps the OP could comment on the precise wording of the problem.

Comment: @RobArthan  I think the intent has to be "receive the correct message".   Nothing else makes sense, or at least, nothing else that  I can think of .

Comment: The OP needs to address these comments. I read the question as just being about whether or not the message was received, regardless of the accuracy of the reception. But it's down to the OP to clarify if he or she wants a useful answer.

Comment: Because " To be confident that a message is received at least once, a system transmits the message n times." It means that the system doesn't know whether the pager received the message or not, so it will send again the same message to make sure that the pager will receive the message !! . I'm also confused about this question in my assignment @@